# Strange Javascript Syntax for "repeating" a method call

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

I've just stumbled across the following javascript snippet in some production code. It works in Chrome & IE but it's not a syntax that I've seen before. The specific snippet is using the jquery vegas plugin to rotate some image background on a timer and overlay a transparent pixel grid on the images.

Here's the code in production.

```
$(function () {
    $.vegas('slideshow', {
        delay: 10000,
        backgrounds: [
            { src: '@Url.Content("~/Images/1.jpg")', fade: 3000 },
            { src: '@Url.Content("~/Images/2.jpg")', fade: 3000 }
        ]
    })('overlay', {            //<<<----- LOOK AT THOSE TOUCHING PARENTHESES
        src: '@Url.Content("~/Content/Overlays/02.png")'
    });
});
```

And here's what it would seem to be equivalent to in more "readable" form.

```
$(function () {
    $.vegas('slideshow', {
        delay: 10000,
        backgrounds: [
            { src: '@Url.Content("~/Images/1.jpg")', fade: 3000 },
            { src: '@Url.Content("~/Images/2.jpg")', fade: 3000 }
        ]
    })

    $.vegas('overlay', {
        src: '@Url.Content("~/Content/Overlays/02.png")'
    });
});
```

So it appears that passing a second set of parameters in a second pair of parentheses, will re-execute the same method a second time with a second set of params, but I'm struggling to find the terminology to search for this type of javascript syntax as it's not something I've seen in other languages.

Can anyone explain.

Comment: Is it possible that a call to `$.vegas()` returns another `vegas()` function reference, which can then be called immediately?

Comment: Isn't simply $.vegas() that returns itself as return value? It's just a not so readable form of fluent interface for methods chaining

Comment: It looks like `vegas` returns the function itself, so adding another pair of `()` after the call would call that same function again with other parameters

Comment: This is only possible, if the function returns itself, so that the result of the function is again a function that can be called again (directly). This could be referred to as `chaining`.

Comment: *sigh*... that makes perfect sense... I'm obviously having an extremely slow-brain day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a form of [method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining), but the method returns a method instead of an object.

The usual form of method chaining is to return the object (`this`), so that you can call another method on the same object:

```
$.vegas( ... ).vegas( ... );
```

When the method returns the method instead of the object, you can call it again without specifying the name:

```
$.vegas( ... )( ... );
```

Answer (score 2):

An anonymous function in JavaScript is often used with the same syntax. I believe right after declaring a function you can call it using ()

Looks like $.vegas() is being chained or called again.

If $.vegas() returns itself then you can chain calls to it in this fashion.

Maybe search chaining function calls.

Answer (score 2):

You have something like this:

```
$.vegas()()
```

Which seemingly returns the function value by $.vegas() and after then again it calls to the function.

For eg. if $.vegas() returns `something` then it would now call like this: `something()`